# How to Expand a Default Angular UI Tree Node

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, nodes, angular-ui-tree

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="locationSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog narrow-modal" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Search for Locations</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tree-container">                  
                    <section>
                        <h2>Browse for Locations</h2>
                        <div ui-tree="" data-drag-enabled="false" id="tree-root">
                            <ul ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data">
                                <li ng-repeat="item in data" ui-tree-node="" collapsed="!item.ItemsRetrieved" ng-include="item.Place || item.$hashkey == undefined ? 'parent_items_renderer' : 'terminal_item_renderer' " ></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="parent_items_renderer">
                            <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content" ng-class="{'tree-node-open': !collapsed}" ng-click="toggle(item); convertObjs(item)">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" ng-class="{'fa-caret-right': collapsed, 'fa-caret-down': !collapsed}"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker" ng-class="{'text-blue': !collapsed}"></i>
                                <span class="" ng-bind-html="item.PlaceName"></span>
                            </div>
                            <ul ng-if="item.Place != null" ui-tree-nodes ng-model="item.Place" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                                <li ng-repeat="item in item.Place" ui-tree-node collapsed="!item.ItemsRetrieved" ng-include="item.Place ? 'parent_items_renderer' :  'terminal_item_renderer' "  on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished"> </li>
                            </ul>

                        </script>
                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="terminal_item_renderer">
                            <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content" ng-class="{'tree-node-open': !collapsed}" ng-click="addLocation(item)">
                                <a href title="Add Location"><span class="" ng-bind-html="item.PlaceName"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </script>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JSON data object that contains the location data is an hierarchical collection of Places:

```
{  
   "PlaceHierarchy":{  
      "Places":{  
         "Place":{  
            "PlaceID":"1000",
            "PlaceTypeID":"5",
            "PlaceName":"Company",
            "AbbrName":"Company",
            "Place":[  
               {  
                  "PlaceID":"2000",
                  "PlaceTypeID":"4",
                  "PlaceName":"Region",
                  "AbbrName":"ThePlace",
                  "Place":[  
                     {  
                        "PlaceID":"3000",
                        "PlaceTypeID":"3",
                        "PlaceName":"SubRegion",
                        "AbbrName":"TheSubPlace",
                        "Place":[  
                           {  
                              "PlaceID":"4000",
                              "PlaceTypeID":"2",
                              "PlaceName":"SubSubRegion",
                              "AbbrName":"TheSubSubPlace",
                              "Place":[  
                                 {  
                                    "PlaceID":"5000",
                                    "PlaceTypeID":"1",
                                    "PlaceName":"Building",
                                    "AbbrName":"Building",
                                    "Place":[  
                                       {  
                                          "PlaceID":"5001",
                                          "PlaceTypeID":"6",
                                          "PlaceName":"Lobby",
                                          "AbbrName":"Lobby"
                                       },
                                       {  
                                          "PlaceID":"5002",
                                          "PlaceTypeID":"6",
                                          "PlaceName":"Lobby 2",
                                          "AbbrName":"Lobby2"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I get that JSON back from the API, I need to process the data to make sure that all nodes are arrays. I do it like this:

```
$scope.processLocationNodes = function (nodes) {
        for (var node in nodes) {
            if (angular.isArray(node)) {
                $scope.processLocationNodes(node);
            } else {
                $scope.convertObjs(node);
            };
        }
    };

$scope.convertObjs = function (item) {

        angular.forEach(item.Place, function (items) {
            if (items != undefined && !angular.isString(items)) {
                if (items.Place && !angular.isArray(items.Place)) {
                    var PlaceObj = items.Place;
                    items.Place = [];
                    items.Place.push(PlaceObj);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Now, when the modal is shown, the data properly displays and the tree works as expected. The only problem is, I want to default the tree to expand to the node of the Default Place of the user. I do that by the following logic:

The onFinishRender directive (debugging the code shows that this is hit):

```
app.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The ngRepeatFinished function is as follows:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        var rootScope = $scope.getRootNodesScope();

        if (rootScope != undefined) {
            rootScope.collapseAll();
            $scope.expandNode($scope.defaultPlace);
        }
    });

$scope.getRootNodesScope = function() {
        return angular.element(document.getElementById("tree-root")).scope().$nodesScope.childNodes()[0];
    }

$scope.expandNode = function(nodeId) {

        // We need to get the whole path to the node to open all the nodes on the path
        var parentScopes = $scope.getScopePath(nodeId);

        for (var i = 0; i < parentScopes.length; i++) {
            parentScopes[i].expand();
        }

    };

$scope.getScopePath = function (nodeId) {
    return $scope.getScopePathIter(nodeId, $scope.getRootNodesScope(), []);
};

$scope.getScopePathIter = function(nodeId, scope, parentScopeList) {

        if (!scope) return null;

        var newParentScopeList = parentScopeList.slice();
        newParentScopeList.push(scope);

        if (scope.$modelValue && scope.$modelValue.id === nodeId) return newParentScopeList;

        var foundScopesPath = null;
        var childNodes = scope.childNodes();

        for (var i = 0; foundScopesPath === null && i < childNodes.length; i++) {
            foundScopesPath = $scope.getScopePathIter(nodeId, childNodes[i], newParentScopeList);
        }

        return foundScopesPath;
    };
```

Now, here's what my problem is:

First of all at the **angular.element(document.getElementById("tree-root")).scope().$nodesScope.childNodes()[0]** code, "childNodes()" is empty. No childNodes exist at all. Thus, the code has nothing to collapse or expand. I don't know why the childNodes collection is empty.

Second, once I figure that out, I can see what the actual NodeId is for a specific node and then be able to expand the tree to that node using the $scope.defaultPlace object.

Essentially, I just need to know why the childNodes collection is empty.

Comment: Hi...anyone got answer to this?? Please let me know if you have any..